# CoreData BUG?: Binding to NSAttributedString causes crash when removing entity from context

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, uikit

I'm taking a non-optional NSAttributedString from CoreData and passing it as a binding to be used in a UIKit `UITextView`. Everything works fine, except that the app crashes when deleting the CoreData entity instance that holds the NSAttributedString `context.delete(entity)`.

I've found that if I create a computed `Binding<NSAttributedString>` var as a roundabout way to pass the variable as a binding, it doesn't crash, but it does when using the normal way of passing bindings -- with a `$`.

I've also found that it doesn't crash if I make `NSAttributedString` an optional `NSAttributedString?` -- then I can use the `$` method.

It also doesn't crash when using a String instead of NSAttributedString, regardless of which way you pass it as binding.

Any idea why? **The error report mentions `_assertionFailure`.** Here's my code and error report:

```
struct EntityView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @ObservedObject var entity: Entity
    
    private var fancyTextBinding: Binding<NSAttributedString> {
        Binding<NSAttributedString> (
            get: { entity.fancyText },
            set: { newValue in entity.fancyText = newValue }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                UITextPort(text: $entity.fancyText) // Crashes when clicking the delete button bellow
                //UITextPort(text: fancyTextBinding) // Doesn't crash
                Spacer()
                Button("Delete") {
                    context.delete(entity)
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}

struct UITextPort: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: NSAttributedString
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let editor = context.coordinator.editor
        
        return editor
    }
    func updateUIView(_ editor: UITextView, context: Context) {
        editor.attributedText = text
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        @Binding var text: NSAttributedString
        
        init(text: Binding<NSAttributedString>) {
            self._text = text
        }
        
        public lazy var editor: UITextView = {
            let editor = UITextView()
            editor.delegate = self
            
            return editor
        }()
        
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            text = textView.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Entity: NSManagedObject {
    public static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var fancyText: NSAttributedString // Doesn't crash when making this an optional
}

extension Entity : Identifiable {

}
```

[image: CoreData screenshot]

**Error report:**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process: exc handler [12673]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d615a98 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 392
1   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d6157fd closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 269
2   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d6156ab closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 379
3   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d615254 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 228
4   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d61548c _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 44
5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d889727 specialized _pop<A>(from:as:count:) + 215
6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d6fed7b closure #2 in KeyPath._projectReadOnly(from:) + 987
7   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d6fe8e7 KeyPath._projectReadOnly(from:) + 263
8   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d70153f swift_getAtKeyPath + 15
9   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d8f0e3c swift_readAtKeyPath + 60
10  SwiftUI                                0x11096f9a9 0x10fa9c000 + 15546793
11  SwiftUI                                0x11079a5e0 0x10fa9c000 + 13624800
12  test                                   0x10b86cd37 closure #1 in closure #1 in EntityView.body.getter + 359 (EntityView.swift:24)
13  test                                   0x10b86dedc partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in EntityView.body.getter + 60
14  SwiftUI                                0x110b7049f 0x10fa9c000 + 17646751
15  test                                   0x10b86ca0f closure #1 in EntityView.body.getter + 495 (EntityView.swift:23)
16  test                                   0x10b86cbbc partial apply for closure #1 in EntityView.body.getter + 60
17  SwiftUI                                0x11079b01f 0x10fa9c000 + 13627423
18  test                                   0x10b86c728 EntityView.body.getter + 584 (EntityView.swift:22)
19  test                                   0x10b86d9bc protocol witness for View.body.getter in conformance EntityView + 60
20  SwiftUI                                0x11003cf9a 0x10fa9c000 + 5902234
21  SwiftUI                                0x1107a7538 0x10fa9c000 + 13677880
22  SwiftUI                                0x11003cee4 0x10fa9c000 + 5902052
23  SwiftUI                                0x1107a7a73 0x10fa9c000 + 13679219
24  SwiftUI                                0x10fe73839 0x10fa9c000 + 4028473
25  AttributeGraph                      0x7ff820ff174a AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 548
26  AttributeGraph                      0x7ff820ff1eff AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 437
27  AttributeGraph                      0x7ff820ffea6f AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 959
28  SwiftUI                                0x110ca6d9e 0x10fa9c000 + 18918814
29  SwiftUI                                0x110ca94b0 0x10fa9c000 + 18928816
30  SwiftUI                                0x1102abcbe 0x10fa9c000 + 8453310
31  SwiftUI                                0x110af1339 0x10fa9c000 + 17126201
32  SwiftUI                                0x110ae8e86 0x10fa9c000 + 17092230
33  SwiftUI                                0x1102abb5c 0x10fa9c000 + 8452956
34  SwiftUI                                0x110ca9489 0x10fa9c000 + 18928777
35  SwiftUI                                0x110ca93dd 0x10fa9c000 + 18928605
36  SwiftUI                                0x1105ce418 0x10fa9c000 + 11740184
37  SwiftUI                                0x10ffb8313 0x10fa9c000 + 5358355
38  SwiftUI                                0x10ffb82ac 0x10fa9c000 + 5358252
39  SwiftUI                                0x10ffb838a 0x10fa9c000 + 5358474
40  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003b1c12 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
41  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003ac57f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 515
42  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003acaa2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1121
43  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003ac264 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
44  GraphicsServices                    0x7ff809b4024e GSEventRunModal + 139
45  UIKitCore                              0x10cd1b7bf -[UIApplication _run] + 994
46  UIKitCore                              0x10cd205de UIApplicationMain + 123
47  SwiftUI                                0x110b8c5ed 0x10fa9c000 + 17761773
48  SwiftUI                                0x110b8c4a6 0x10fa9c000 + 17761446
49  SwiftUI                                0x1102a2610 0x10fa9c000 + 8414736
50  test                                   0x10b86b80e static testApp.$main() + 30 (testApp.swift:10)
51  test                                   0x10b86b8c9 main + 9
52  dyld_sim                               0x10ba22384 start_sim + 10
53  dyld                                   0x11b2be41f start + 1903
```